# Hide columns of a year

Tags: vba, excel

I want to hide all columns of dates which years aren't the last 2 years. For that (I don't know whether it is the correct approach or not) I've been doing some research given that I know nothing about Excel programming, and I've created this VBA script but it does not seem to work:

```
Function OcultarFechas(Range)
Rg1 = Range ' B2:AA2
Flag = "ok"
For Each c1 In Range(Rg1).Cells
    If Year(c1) <> Year(Date) Then
        Columns(c1.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Flag = "notok"
    End If
    If Flag = "notok" Then Exit For
    Next c1
End Function
```

It would be preferable that the scripts executes when I open the spreadsheet but right now with this code I think I need to call the function on a cell like: "=OcultarFechas(B2:AA2)".

PS. the dates are ordered that's why I exit the for loop when the current year is found, and from that column I need to keep them unhidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hide a column using UDF.

Try something like this...

```
Sub HideColumns()
Dim c As Long, lc As Long
lc = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns.Hidden = False
For c = 2 To lc
    If Year(Cells(2, c)) < Year(Date) Then
        Columns(c).Hidden = True
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

The code above will find the last column used in Row2 and loop through column 2 to the last column found and check the year condition and hide the column accordingly.

To call this procedure automatically when you open the workbook, place the following code on ThisWorkbook Module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call HideColumns
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this out and works pretty nice, just one issue one column was hidden but there was no content inside it but I could reformat that and it'll work perfect. How can I do this automatically every time I open the spreadsheet? Thanks

Comment: Edited the solution. Please have a look.

Comment: To skip a column if a cell in that column in Row2 is empty, change the IF statement with --- If Year(Cells(2, c)) < Year(Date) And Cells(2, c) <> "" Then